# 1D numpy array which is shifted to the right for each consecutive row in a new 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to optimise some code by removing for loops and using numpy arrays only as I am working with large data sets.

I would like to take a 1D numpy array, for example:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and produce a 2D numpy array whereby the value in each column shifts along a place, for example in the case above for a I wish to have a function which returns:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5]
 [0 1 2 3 4]
 [0 0 1 2 3]
 [0 0 0 1 2]
 [0 0 0 0 1]]
```

I have found examples which use the strides function to do something similar to produce, for example:

```
[[1 2 3]
 [2 3 4]
 [3 4 5]]
```

However I am trying to shift each of my columns in the other direction. Alternatively, one can view the problem as putting the first element of a on the first diagonal, the second element on the second diagonal and so on. However, I would like to stress again how I would like to avoid using a for, while or if loop entirely. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Such a matrix is an example of a [Toeplitz matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toeplitz_matrix).  You could use [`scipy.linalg.toeplitz`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.toeplitz.html) to create it:

```
In [32]: from scipy.linalg import toeplitz

In [33]: a = range(1,6)

In [34]: toeplitz(a, np.zeros_like(a)).T
Out[34]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

---

Inspired by @EelcoHoogendoorn's answer, here's a variation that doesn't use as much memory as `scipy.linalg.toeplitz`:

```
In [47]: from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

In [48]: a
Out[48]: array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [49]: t = as_strided(np.r_[a[::-1], np.zeros_like(a)], shape=(a.size,a.size), strides=(a.itemsize, a.itemsize))[:,::-1]

In [50]: t
Out[50]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [0, 0, 1, 2, 3],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

The result should be treated as a "read only" array.  Otherwise, you'll be in for some surprises when you change an element.  For example:

```
In [51]: t[0,2] = 99

In [52]: t
Out[52]: 
array([[ 1,  2, 99,  4,  5],
       [ 0,  1,  2, 99,  4],
       [ 0,  0,  1,  2, 99],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  1,  2],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  1]])
```

Comment: Or `triu(circulant(a).T)`, but some timing tests suggest your way is consistently faster.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the indexing-tricks based solution. Not nearly as elegant as the toeplitz solution already posted, but should memory consumption or performance be a concern, it is to be preferred. As demonstrated, this also makes it easy to subsequently manipulate the entries of the matrix in a consistent manner.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(5)+1

def toeplitz_view(a):
    b = np.concatenate((np.zeros_like(a),a))
    i = a.itemsize
    v = np.lib.index_tricks.as_strided(b,
        shape=(len(b),)*2,
        strides=(-i, i))
    #return a view on the 'original' data as well, for manipulation
    return v[:len(a), len(a):], b[len(a):]        

v, a = toeplitz_view(a)
print v
a[0] = 10
v[2,1] = -1
print v
```

Comment: Neat use of `as_strided`!  For kicks, here's a rather dense one-liner: `as_strided(np.r_[a[::-1], np.zeros_like(a)], shape=(a.size,a.size), strides=(a.itemsize, a.itemsize))[:,::-1]`